# With anycast DNS, is it the IP or the FQDN that is doing it?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, anycast

i am somewhat new to anycast and i want to know if it works on the IP or the FQDN.
The reason i ask is, i have a anycastDNS account with a provider. And i would like to use my own domain name to make it whitelabel.
So i could use a CNAME record to point to their nameservers but that would result in 2 DNS lookups.
Or could i just create an A record and point it to the IP address, that nameserver record is pointing to?
By pointing that A record do i defeat the while anycast feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anycast is on the "ip level"

It pretty much has multiple providers broadcasting to the internet saying the IP is here and its up to the routers between the client and servers to decide which is the quickest location to the endpoint.

also a CNAME if its within the same zone file is a single lookup

Comment: sounds good. so me creating an A record pointing to one of my providers nameserver IPs will indeed still have the anycast functionality to it.

Comment: actually, i supose then by me having an A Record pointing to their IPs, and using that A Record for other domains to use as their nameserver. then my domain is going to get heaps of DNS queries on that A Record isn't it? maybe there is no good way to whitelabel the nameserver